# i get too many Queries per day YouTube Data API v3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

i make this api just to try something but i get too many Queries per day for 5 result only
[image]

and I am the only one who uses it

Is there an error I've done ?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
$search = $_GET['search'];
$item = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=".urlencode($search)."&type=video&key=secret&maxResults=5"))->items;
$title = [];
$videoId = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($item); $i++) { 
$title[$i] = $item[$i]->snippet->title;
$videoId[$i] = $item[$i]->id->videoId;

}
$echo["title"] = $title;
$echo["videoId"] = $videoId;
echo json_encode($echo);
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. What is your quota limit? 2. Are you _certain_ you're the only one? Look at your logs. If you're not gating this behind authentication you're a prime target for other people. 3. You should change your API key in case you've leaked it accidentally. 4. Do you _need_ fresh results every single time you do a search? Cache them otherwise. 5. If none of the previous are the problem, then you need to start giving Google money to increase your quota.

Comment: @Sammitch i changed my key already but the only problem why i get too many quotes 10.000 per day not something i can used just from testing my api in 10 minutes